# remember history in cmd.exe?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, history

Is it possible to remember the command history in CMD.EXE (Windows 7), between sessions?

Or is there some enhancement/wrapper/replacement which has this (basic IMO) feature?

Comment: Maybe DOSKEY still works ... look into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is basic history functionality for the current session using <kbd>F7</kbd>, although across sessions you'll want [**PyCmd**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pycmd/).

PyCmd is a Python wrapper for cmd.exe which brings a couple features of traditional UNIX-based shells to the table, including command history and "smart" tab completion.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. PyCmd seemed nice to me, but rather buggy (and not very active). https://sourceforge.net/projects/pycmd/forums/forum/951390/topic/4036676